# Not able to connect odoo using ripcord

Tags: connection

Here is my code.

```
require_once('ripcord-master/ripcord.php');
$url = "http://localhost:8069";           //ODOO  Server Url
$db ="test";                   //Database Name
$username = "test1@gmail.com";  //UserName 
$password = "password";                 //Password
$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());
print_r($uid);  //1
```

I an getting below response:

```
Array ( [faultCode] => 1 [faultString] => Traceback (most recent call last): File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 69, in xmlrpc_2 response = self._xmlrpc(service) File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 49, in _xmlrpc result = dispatch_rpc(service, method, params) File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 140, in dispatch_rpc result = dispatch(method, params) File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/common.py", line 56, in dispatch return g[exp_method_name](*params) File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/common.py", line 27, in exp_authenticate return res_users.authenticate(db, login, password, {**user_agent_env, 'interactive': False}) TypeError: 'list' object is not a mapping )
```

Please help me with this issue.